# How do I build a library into a .jar with Android Studio 1.1?

Tags: android-studio

In the [docs](https://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html), it says:

> Note: You need SDK Tools r14 or newer to use the new library module
>   feature that generates each library module into its own JAR file.

I have the latest SDK Tools, so I should be able to do this. But when I build my library (the compile completes without errors) I can't find any .jar file.

I set up the module in question as an "Android Library" with no Activity. It's using gradle build scripts. I'm building this to be a plugin for a Unity3d project, so it needs to be a .jar built with JDK 1.6.

Comment: Can you give more details - is it android or java library? Do you use gradle/maven/ant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is that something must depend on the library for it to be built into a jar file.

So making an empty application module that depends on the library made it generate the jar. It is found in

app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\ProjectName\LibraryName\